# What would you do if I told you+subordinate clause

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

there are a couple of sentences that I have been having trouble with lately. I'll start with an example:

- I'd be lying if I said I have never considered moving.(referring to the present)

That's how I'd say it, and I think it's correct, although I've asked a native and he told me he'd be more likely to say "I had never considered." Despite this, I've found examples on the Internet which use the present perfect. It's so confusing.

There are some other examples that come to my mind which I find just as confusing. for example, is it

-what would you do if I told you I still love you?

-what would you do if I told you i still loved you?(both referring to a present situation)

I've found both on the Internet, and I just can't figure out which one is right. By right I mean both what grammarians would consider appropriate, and what a native speaker of English would be more likely to find idiomatic, which is often not the same as the grammatically correct option. Could you please help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue you are brushing up against is, I think, the English subjunctive tense. Native English speakers use a tense for hypothetical or contrary-to-fact situations that marks these as things that are not *necessarily* true. An illustrative example might be "If I were a thief, I think I would be good at stealing wallets." This was in the subjunctive tense; I'm not actually a thief, and I don't necessarily want to imply that I am one, so the use of "were" helps mark the statement as hypothetical.

Of course, the problem is that the subjunctive case just doesn't get used all that consistently by native English speakers. I suspect this is because it's often really formal sounding and maybe a little redundant at times. I mean, the use of the word "if" in the example above already marks the statement as hypothetical to a degree.

In your first example, I agree that "had" makes more sense, just because the proper subjunctive verb in the first part is "would." That is, "I'd" is short for "I would," as in *if this thing **were** true about me, I **would** be a liar*. "Had" matches the tense of "would" in that sense better than "have" does because the English subjunctive tends to match more closely the past tense than the present one in form. But I think that's a pretty tricky example.

As for your second example, I believe the second one is more correct for the same reason--"loved" matches "would" better than "love" does, but I suspect plenty of native speakers would stumble on that one as well, or simply not notice the difference.

More information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: Sorry, there is not any "subjunctive tense" in English. There is a lot of misinformation under that heading on the Web.

Comment: If you mean that it is a verb "mood" rather than a true "tense," then I would agree, but otherwise I would like to see some resources to support that contention.

Comment: No, I mean that "subjunctive" is a term that's best to avoid in English grammar, since nobody knows what it means, and many different things are called "subjunctive" that aren't. There are a few constructions -- relatively rare -- that can be called "subjunctive" with a straight face. But not the ones the book tells you. The only ones you can actually tell are mandative verbs in the third person singular present, and mandative verb phrases starting with auxiliary _be_. This is a very small sample of possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately not everyone is French :)